# Passing placeholders and labels to common input components, Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I have made a common reusable input field component. Now, the issue is that the placeholders and labels for this input component are static. How can I pass place holders and labels dynamically for the component i am calling this component from!

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="common-location">
            <mat-label>**Search By Location**</mat-label> // {{label that i would pass}}
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="**{{placeHolder}}**" formControlName="location" name="location" aria-label="Location" [matAutocomplete]="auto"> //placeholder that should be passed
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="location">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let places of predictions" [value]="places.description">
                    <span>{{places.description}}</span>
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <mat-error>Please enter location of job.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

> And I am calling this component from outside as:

```
<app-autocomplete (formReady)="addFormControl('location', $event)" [placeHolder]="Location"></app-autocomplete>
```

> trying to send placeholder and trying to bind in the common component not working for me.

I am new to this, I have worked with Ember and I know that we can pass data the same way as I am trying to pass here and then binding the same works there. How does it work in Angular?

Comment: You should be able to use `[placeholder]="placeHolder"` inside the common component

Comment: Not Working!! With this.

Comment: the component which has label, needs to have `@Input() placeholder`, then when you use it you do as he told you above

Comment: It should do, here is a stackblitz demo of it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxz9vv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html If it's still not working, please create a stackblitz that reproduces the issue

Comment: That worked fine!! Thanks user184994 and Hussein :)